# Trouble outputting data to local file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, io

I've been teaching myself Ruby and I'm quite stuck trying to output information to a text file. The file is created, there are no errors thrown, but nothing is being written to the file. I've chosen to amend the file vs. writing to it, as I don't want the data to be overwritten. I know this will be a simple answer but I've been beating my head against a wall for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Here's my controller

```
class EntriesController < InheritedResources::Base
   actions :new, :show, :index, :edit, :update
   before_filter :set_message, :only => [:update]

   def save_to_file
    playlist = 'playlist.txt'
    File.open(playlist, 'a+') do |entry|
      entry.each do |entry|
        f.puts '#{entry.song}  by  #{entry.artist}  on  #{entry.album}'
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
    if @entry.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your song was added"
      save_to_file
      redirect_to entries_path
     else
      flash[:error] = "Your song wasn't added. Please check all info and try agian."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:artist, :album, :song)
  end

  def set_message
    flash[:warning] = "Are you sure you want to overwrite this song information?"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 errors here:

```
def save_to_file
  playlist = 'playlist.txt'
  File.open(playlist, 'a+') do |entry|  # 1
    entry.each do |entry| # 2
      f.puts '#{entry.song}  by  #{entry.artist}  on  #{entry.album}' # 3 and 4
    end
  end
end
```

1. `|entry|` is an instance of opened `File` (`playlist.txt`) here, not an instance of `Entry` class. Syntax is correct (file is opened correctly), but it seems there's some confusion (logic error).
2. You want to refer to created `Entry` model, you need to do that via an instance variable `@entry` or, better, pass it as a parameter to function `save_to_file`. Since `entry` refers to 1 object and not to a collection, you don't need `each` there.
3. `f` is not defined so trying to call any method on that will cause an error. You probably meant to use variable from p.1 here.
4. String interpolation (such as `"#{entry.song}"`) doesn't work in single quotes, you need to use double quotes instead.

Assuming the points above I'd change your code to the following:

```
def save_to_file(entry)
  playlist = 'playlist.txt'
  File.open(playlist, 'a+') do |f|
    f.puts "#{entry.song} by #{entry.artist} on #{entry.album}"
  end
end
```

And call it from `EntriesController#create` method as `save_to_file(@entry)`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your patience and thoughtful answer. I was pretty sure that my error lied somewhere in the method arguments or basic logic, but there were enough errors that I couldn't debug it. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

You use `entry` 3 times it looks like a bug.

```
File.open(playlist, 'a') do |f|
  entry.each do |e|
    f.puts "#{e.song}  by  #{e.artist}  on  #{e.album}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I haven't been using Rails for ages, but shouldn't this also be `Entry.each` to iterate over the instances of the `Entry` class?

Answer (score 0):

As I think error in this part because single quoted string does not support string interpolation.

```
    f.puts '#{e.song}  by  #{e.artist}  on  #{e.album}'
```

Could you try this

```
  f.puts "#{e.song} by #{e.artist} on #{e.album}"
```